# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'info'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a VS C# project (project1) that compiles and works fine without any errors.

I have created a second project (project2) that adds a number of files as links from the first project. I've added all the necessary references etc. I've created a conditional compilation symbol for project2. Project2 is giving one error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'info' of 'Curve.Curve(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)'

```
public CurveCollection(List<Rhino.Geometry.Curve> curves) 
{
      this.CurveList = this.CurveList;
}
```

I've searched through the forums to try and find why this error is being caused, and I'm at a loss.

Can someone shed some light on what I may be missing?

Comment: Something doesn't look right here, are you sure this is line that throws? Can you double check please

Comment: You initiallized this variable with itself value.

Answer (score 1):

As i said this line of code which you wrote doesnt do anything it just initialleze `this.CurveList` as its value, i think you should change yours to this:-

```
public CurveCollection(List<Rhino.Geometry.Curve> curves) 
{
    this.CurveList = curves;
}
```